# Android -Custom Navigation Drawer background list scrolls/focused

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, navigation-drawer

I have a custom Navigation Drawer with a couple of `TextViews`. Here is the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="First Item" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/gplus_color_1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:text="Second Item"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/second" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is, if I don't assign any `onClick()` for the `TextView`, then the touch is reflected on the `ListView` which is in the background. Say, for the second `TextView` I assigned an onClick listener but for the first `TextView` I didn't, when I touch on the first `TextView` the list item behind the drawer gets selected but not for the second. How do I keep the focus on the navigation drawer items when the drawer is opened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add android:clickable="true" to ur LinearLayout.
It stop focusing to the background list.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
```